# Can I use RandomUnderSampler for categorical data as well?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, imbalanced-data

AFAIK, unlike SMOTE,  RandomUnderSampler selects a subset of the data. But I am not quite confident to use it for categorical data.

So, is it really applicable for categorical data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under/Over sampling has nothing to do with features. It relies on **targets** and under/oversamples majority/minority class, no matter whatheter it is composed of continuous variables, categorical ones, or elephants :)